# How do I search for a specific element value in an ArrayList of objects?

Tags: java, arraylist

Example:
There is an `ArrayList <Patients>` with `Patient` having attributes such as `Name`, `BirthDate`, `cpf`., you must search through the `ArrayList` of patients for the patient with the name "Luis" and return their index in the list.

I have tried run on `ArrayList` and get with `.contains` but do not have success.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: `contains` wouldn't normally be the right tool unless you already have a reference to the actual object in the list. Normally you'd use an iterator or something from `java.util.stream`.

Comment: As per previous comment, `contains` checks the references, not the contents of each object in the list

Comment: You can use for loop to filter.

    for(Patient patient: patients){
       if(a.getName().equal("Luis))
    }

or you can use java stream:

    List<Patient> patient = patients.stream().filter(patient -> patient .getName().equal("Luis)).collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the list and request the name, check the name for its correctness.`

```
public static Patient getPatient(List<Patient> patients, String wantedName){
    Patient wantedPatient = null;
        for(Patient patient: patients){
            if(patient.getName().equals(wantedName)){
                wantedPatient = patient;
                break;
            }
        }
    return patient;
}
```

Though be aware that null is returned in case a name could not be matched.
Alternatevily I would suggest you using a Map, where every name is a key to a Patient object.
Much more comfortable then you'd only to call

```
Patient patient = map.get(patientName);
```

.contains only gives you a boolean back IF the list contains an Object which equals the one you are comparing against.

Answer (score -1):

```
ArrayList <Patients> patients;

for (Patient patient : patients) {
    if (patient.Name.equals("Luis")) {
        return patients.indexOf(patient);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.